# Check Internet Connectivity & Output into txt file [PERL]

Tags: perl

I am trying to get some code which allows me to check "internetconnectivity" and store a boolean value (0, 1) into a text file. I am having issues with the code updating changes to internet connectivity, it works on initial execution but when I change the internet environment the text file fails to be updated. I have tried to use an infinite while loop to allow continuous checking in conjunction with sleep() to prevent my computer from frying itself.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
use strict;

use Net::Ping;

my $filename = 'internetConnectivityStorage.txt';
open(my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename);

while() {
    my $x = Net::Ping->new("icmp");
    if ($x->ping("8.8.8.8", 1)) {
        print $fh "1";
    } else {
        print $fh "0";
    }
    close($fh);
    sleep(3)
}
```

PS. Am noob and new to perl. Surviving off google searches and guesses ;)

Comment: I have fixed the indentation in your code example. You're welcome, but please consider doing it yourself in the future. Proper indentation is an essential tool for understanding code. If you're asking a large number of strangers to read and understand your code, then it is a bit rude not to put effort in to make that as easy as possible.

Comment: *Surviving off google searches and guesses* You would be far better advised to get [a good book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920049517.do).

Comment: @DaveCross or use the greatest access to information, the internet.

Comment: Well, you've already demonstrated that's not working particularly well for you :-)

Comment: @DaveCross considering my question was solved within 12hrs, think its working pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening the file once, but close the filehandle in the while loop, so it won't be updated.
Move `close($fh);` behind the closing curly bracket of the while loop.

Also, I believe the output will be buffered before being written to the file, so you won't see it immediately.
Add `$| = 1;` in the beginning of your script to turn off output buffering.

Comment: Setting `$| = 1` will have no effect on `$fh`. It operates on the currently-selected output file handle, which is initially `STDOUT`, so you would have to write `{ my $old = select $fh; $| = 1; select $old; }`. A much better way is to use the `autoflush` method, as in `$fh->autoflush`, which is much more expressive and doesn't require the use of `select`. Even better, if perl finds an undefined method call on a file handle then it loads `IO::File` and tries again, so there is no need even to add `use IO::File` to your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::Ping;
my $filename = 'internetConnectivityStorage.txt';

while() {
    open(my $fh, '>:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename);
    my $x = Net::Ping->new("icmp");
    print {$fh} ($x->ping("8.8.8.8", 1)) ? 1 : 0;
    close($fh);
    sleep(3)
}
```

A few changes. I moved the open to the while loop, I think you want to update the contents of the file on each iteration of the while loop.

Comment: If you re-open the file in each iteration I'd suggest _appending_ to the file (`>>`) instead of overwriting (`>`) . Also the flushing isn't necessary when you close the file after printing.

Comment: I got the impression that the OP just needed the last result as some sort of semaphore file. as the for the flushing, your right and I've edited to reflect that.

Comment: Ahh, I must confess I have overlooked that. Of course you are right then, the last line is sufficient.